# AJAX запрос срабатывает на странице только один (первый) раз

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

В учебных целях сделал страницу, где бы генерировались карточки со случайной картинкой с сайта unsplash.com, и текстом - рыбой с сайта fish-text.ru. Не могу понять, почему AJAX запрос срабатывает только для первой карточки. Не могу понять, что не так...

```
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
        <div class="float-left m-2" style="width: 200px">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200?sig=<?= $i ?>" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card Title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text" id="spam" ></p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>            

<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://fish-text.ru/get?format=html&number=1',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (res) {
                $('#spam').html(res);
            },
        })   
</script>
```

Comment: с чего ты взял-то что один раз? У тебя в php что написано? Если статический текст, то оно выполняется нормально(скорее всего), если динамический, то кидай php сюда

Comment: Спасибо. Текст динамический, т.е. с каждым обновлением генерируется новое предложение. Не совсем понял - "то кидай php сюда".

Comment: ну генератор текста этого

Answer (score 2):

Потому что Вы в цикле создаете много элементов с одинаковыми `id`:

```
<p class="card-text" id="spam" ></p>
```

Селектор `$('#spam')` находит только один (первый) из них.

---

> Поменял id на class, и все заработало! Но теперь во всех элементах
>   одинаковый текст.

Потому что селектор `$('.spam')` выбирает *все* элементы с таким классом.

```
    let index = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://fish-text.ru/get?format=html&number=' + (index + 1),
        type: 'get',
        success: function (res) {
            $('.spam').eq(index).html(res);
        },
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо! Поменял id на class, и все заработало! Но теперь во всех элементах одинаковый текст.

Comment: @Serg988 Потому что селектор `$('.spam')` выбирает *все* элементы с таким классом. Добавлю ответ через несколько минут.

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не получилось. Опять текст генерируется только в первой карточке. Тут, кстати, в ссылке 'https://fish-text.ru/get?format=html&number=1' последний параметр "1", это не id, а требуемое количество предложений. Текст меняется при каждом обновлении. То есть для получения нового текста необходимо формировать новый запрос.

Comment: @Serg988 Вы понимаете, что мне виден только тот код, который Вы включили в вопрос?

Comment: Да, конечно. Я имел в виду адрес для ajax запроса: url: 'https://fish-text.ru/get?format=html&number=' + (index + 1),

Comment: @Serg988 Опишите, пожалуйста, какое поведение Вы хотите получить.

Comment: @Serg988 ... и как в разные элементы должен попасть разный текст.

Comment: Я хочу получить на странице заданное количество карточек, с разными картинками и разным текстом. И то, и другое рандомное. С картинками проблем нет, а вот с текстом пока не получается. Сейчас пытаюсь что то придумать с добавлением data атрибутов.

Comment: @Serg988 Вы хотите одним запросом получить текст для всех карточек?

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что нужно как то заставить посылать запрос при формировании каждой карточки. Вот и думаю сейчас. Я еще очень и очень начинающий :)

Comment: Идея такова, что при каждом изменении $i в php коде, формировался бы новый запрос. Но пока не приходит в голову, как.

Comment: @Serg988 Как эти запросы отличаются для разных карточек?

Comment: Ну, думаю в php цикле включить в текстовый элемент data-id="<?=$i?>", увеличивающийся для каждой карточки, который как то использовать для формирования разных запросов. Пока не могу реализовать.

Comment: В общем, отказался от использования ajax в данной задаче. Реализовал на php через file_get_contents(). Спасибо за помощь :)